# EE 3.3.0: Mail not being sent for channel entry notification

Tags: channel, email, notification, smtp

Question regarding email.  When I get new entries in a channel, I'm not getting notified, even though I have notifications turned on:

Author notify: no
Entry notification: Yes.  Only one email listed.

I've verified my SMTP settings by sending a test message (Utilities -> Communicate).

I don't see any errors in the Logs --> Email (says "No Email logs found.").

Any thoughts on how to diagnose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was determined to be a bug in 3.2.1 / 3.3.0:

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21819/ee-3.3.0-not-sending-channel-entry-notifications